# What is the opposite of "She turned him down" in spoken language?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> **[turn somebody/something  down](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/turn-down?q=turn%20down)**: means "*​to reject or refuse to consider an offer, a proposal, etc. or the person who makes it*"

What is the opposite of "**She turned him down**" or "**she turned his proposal down**" in spoken language?

we can list formal words such as "**accept**", "**consent**", "**agree**" etc, which are common in written language.

"**turn down**" is used more in spoken language and its opposite should be more common in spoken language.

Answer (score 4):

Following the analogy of a written proposal being rejected by physically turning the paper face down, one might say:

- She *took him up* on his offer.
- She *took up* his offer.